# Deleting page and all nested pages connected to main

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.3. Is any easy way to delete all nested pages when I delete main page?

For example in my table:

```
+-----------------------------+
|id|parent|name               |
+--+------+-------------------+
|67|0     |example name 1     |
+--+------+-------------------+
|68|67    |example name 2     |
+--+------+-------------------+
|58|68    |example name 3     |
+--+------+-------------------+
|65|58    |example name 4     |
+--+------+-------------------+
|70|68    |example name 5     |
+--+------+-------------------+
|66|0     |example name 6     |
+--+------+-------------------+
```

It gives structure like this:

```
example name 1
       |
       +---------example name 2
               |
               +---------example name 3
                      |
                      +---------example name 4
               |
               +---------example name 5  
example name 6
```

When I remove `example name 1` (`id = 58`) nested pages should be remooved too. How to do in php loop or another way in Laravel 5 ?

Comment: Have you given any thought on soft deletes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle it in the model's boot function as well;

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    App\Page::deleted(function($page) {
         App\Page::where('parent_id', $page->id)->delete();
    }); 
}
```

This will recursively handle the nested deletion problem. However, for pages that may be deeply nested or have several relations, this could be a performance issue, where you may want to utilize the queue instead.

**Example**

In your model file, `App\Page` you add this function:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model {
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($page){
             static::where('parent_id', $page->id)->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the best way so far to handle it. +1

Comment: I am not sure how to us boot() function and what about parent: __boot. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @Tomasz This would go in your `App\Page` model. The `boot()` function is a method that Eloquent's `model` implements. You're declaring your own boot method, but you're still calling Eloquent's base method with `parent::boot();`

Comment: I need example of using it.I dont know how to pass `$page` to this function.  Maybe I am too week yet to understand your way of thinking.

Comment: @Tomasz You do not pass `$page` in. This is how laravel deals with [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events). Whenever you delete a model, you can capture the `delete` event. In the callback of the event, your receive the `$model` as a variable. In this case that `$model` is your `$page`. I've added an example in my answer. Hopefully this clears thing sup.

Comment: Now I understood. Perfect solution ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loop. Just firstly delete the article with ID, then with parent_id.

```
$article=Article::findOrFail($id);

$article->delete();

Article::where('parent_id', $id)->delete();
```

Also, you can use `softDelete()` method, if you want to restore deleted articles whenever.

Comment: The problem is that you don't always know the nesting level, if I understood correctly

Comment: He use parent_id. so we can find all the nesting levels of one article.

Comment: Won't work for `example name 3`(parent id=2) when deleting `example name 1` for ex. It will just remove `example name 2`(parent id=1)

Comment: I saw it. his example is not correct or his database structure is wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

You should leverage **onDelete('cascade')** method of the database migration if possible.

Or

You can write a function which will accept a page_id that you want to delete. Call that function recursively until you get all the childs of each level of that page and return them. And finally mass delete them in a single query like:

```
Page::destroy([10, 22, 23, 40 , 55]);
```